# How to fix blank page bug after deploying vuejs project to subdomain?

Tags: vue.js, ftp

the site link works but the page is blank.

I want to deploy on a sub-domain, so I created my ftp account and in my main directory "public_html" I created the "gbconnect" folder.
And my config file looks like:
module. exports = {
publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
? '/gbconnect'
: '/'
}, but I still have the blank page bug. how to solve the problem please.
Before that noted that I had set for the path '/public_html/gbconnect' and the bug still continues.
THANKS!